# How to use ActionListener to add a file path to a Linked List

Tags: java, linked-list, awt, actionlistener, circular-list

I'm trying to make a music player using circular linked list that actually plays music. So far, the linked list doesn't have a problem (as far as I can tell), and I'm having trouble with my `actionPerformed` method. I have 2 buttons, a button to add a song file path to the LinkedList and a play button to play all mp3 files in my linked list

This is GUI for those buttons

```
  public class MPGui extends JFrame implements ActionListener{ 
  JButton btnAdd; 
  JButton btnPlay;

  public MPGui() {

 
  btnAdd = new JButton("+");
  panel.add(btnAdd);
  btnAdd.setBounds(10, 37, 53, 23);
  btnAdd.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 10));
  btnAdd.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
  btnAdd.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
  btnAdd.addActionListener(this);

  btnPlay = new JButton("Play");
  btnPlay.setBounds(180, 11, 61, 23);
  btnPlay.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
  btnPlay.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 10)); 
  btnPlay.setBackground(UIManager.getColor("Button.darkShadow"));
  btnPlay.addActionListener(this);
  panelOperations.add(btnPlay);

  //.... more buttons and frames
```

And this actionPerformed method

```
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    CreateList cl = new CreateList();
    if (e.getSource() == btnAdd){
            JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
            chooser.setDialogTitle("Choose song to load...");
            chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
            songFile = chooser.getSelectedFile().toString();
            fileName = chooser.getSelectedFile().getName();
            songFile = songFile.replace("\\","/");          // my poorly made statements so that they can be taken by my File Reader class
            System.out.println("directory" + songFile);
            String musicPath = "/"+ songFile;
            System.out.println("filename: " + fileName);
            lblShowCurrent.setText(fileName);
            System.out.println(musicPath);
            cl.add(musicPath);    // adds the music path to the linked list
            cl.display();

    }
    else if(e.getSource() == btnPlay){
        System.out.println("beep");
        cl.play();
    }

}
```

And this is my linked list class

```
public class CreateList {
FileReader fr = new FileReader();  // a class that reads my files, also makes it so I can pause play and stop the music
Node current;
public Node head = null;
public Node tail = null;

public class Node {
    String path;
    Node next;
    Node prev;


    public Node(String path) {
        this.path = path;
        current = head;
    }
}
public void play() {
    if (head == null) {
        System.out.println("List is empty");
    } else {
        do {
            String path = current.path;
            fr.play(path);
            current = current.next;

        } while (current != head);
    }
}
public void display(){
    current = head;
    if (head == null) {
        System.out.println("List is empty");
    } else {
        do {
            System.out.println(current.path);

        } while (current != head);
    }

}
public void add(String path) {
    System.out.println("Song added");
    if (head == null) {
        Node new_node = new Node(path);
        new_node.path = path;
        new_node.next = new_node.prev = new_node;
        head = new_node;
        return;
    }

   
    Node last = (head).prev;   

    Node new_node = new Node(path);
    new_node.path = path;
    new_node.next = head;
    (head).prev = new_node;
    new_node.prev = last;
    last.next = new_node;
}
```

When I run this and first add a song, it recognizes that the FilePath is successfully added to the list, but when I press the play button it will say that list is empty. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Hint: focus on the different parts of your application. Start with your list implementation. Note that it has NOTHING to do with audio, players, GUI. Nothing. It is just a data structure. Meaning: write code to **test** your list code, without worrying about anything else. Tests like: create an empty list. Create a list, add one entry ... check that the entry is there. Stuff like that. Ideally, write the test BEFORE you write the corresponding functional code. Run one test, make sure it passes. If not, add more print statements, use a debugger.

Comment: Meaning: first make sure the simple things work, all by their own. Then, when you are convinced that the list works EXACTLY as it should, only then start working on larger things that use the basic things.

Comment: Hint: `new_node.next = new_node.prev = new_node;` ... when you create a new node, why would is NEXT point ... to itself?

Comment: Finally: learn about java naming conventions. You use "_" only for SOME constant. All variables and fields should go camelCase. And if you really want to enable us to help you ... see [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly. As suggested above, you would start by THROW WAY all that GUI stuff. Because the GUI doesnt matter as long as your plain list implementation isnt working correctly.